# add mapping template for API in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-kinesis

I want to add a header (Content-Type) and a mapping template within the integration request of my AWS API Gateway. While following this tutorial, I could easily add those parameters via the console. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-kinesis.html

However, I am unable to figure out the syntax to add them using Terraform. This is my integration request so far:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "kinesis_integration" {
  rest_api_id          = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.shippeo_api_kinesis.id
  resource_id          = aws_api_gateway_resource.shippeo_api_resource_kinesis.id
  http_method          = aws_api_gateway_method.post_json_files_kinesis.http_method
  credentials          = aws_iam_role.shippeo_integration_role.arn
  type                 = "AWS"
  uri                  = "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1:kinesis:action/PutRecord"
  integration_http_method     = "POST"
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_resource.shippeo_api_resource_kinesis
  ]
}
```

How can I specify the **header (Content-Type)+Mapped From** and the **mapping templates** as shown below using Terraform?

[image]
Mapping Template:

```
{
    "StreamName": "$input.params('stream-name')",
    "Data": "$util.base64Encode($input.json('$.Data'))",
    "PartitionKey": "$input.path('$.PartitionKey')"
}
```

In the documentation, **selection_pattern** and **response_templates** is mentioned but I am not sure how to use it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve it with this:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "kinesis_integration" {
  rest_api_id    = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.shippeo_api_kinesis.id
  resource_id    = aws_api_gateway_resource.shippeo_api_resource_kinesis.id
  http_method    = aws_api_gateway_method.post_json_files_kinesis.http_method
  credentials    = aws_iam_role.shippeo_integration_role.arn
  type           = "AWS"
  uri            = "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1:kinesis:action/PutRecord"
  integration_http_method     = "POST"
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_resource.shippeo_api_resource_kinesis
  ]

  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = <<REQUEST_TEMPLATE
    {
        "StreamName": "$input.params('stream-name')",
        "Data": "$util.base64Encode($input.json('$.Data'))",
        "PartitionKey": "$input.path('$.PartitionKey')"
    }
  REQUEST_TEMPLATE
  }

  passthrough_behavior = "WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES"
}
```